# Is it necessary to look, website same in all browser?

Tags: css, xhtml

- Is it necessary to look, website same
  in all browser? Is it a legal requirement in some country?
- isn't it need of pixel perfection ( to inch to inch match with Design) a
  madness?
- isn't it asking IE6 Pixel perfection,
  as of now, is a madness?
- Is it sin to to use JavaScript for visual enhancement, like to enable border radius in IE using JavaScript and from CSS in other browsers?

How to explain clinet that website will never look , pixel perfect on all browsers on all os and devices?

Comment: I think the close brigade will come in any second and close this question. It's not really a question, but a rant. :P (One that I agree with!)

Comment: You should send your client this link: http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/ :)

Comment: Wow, I thought you were trolling. Cheapest domain to buy ever.

Comment: Seriously, "a legal requirement"?! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "How to explain clinet that website will never look , pixel perfect on all browsers on all os and devices?"

I haven't found a "killer" argument yet.  Here are the ones that have had some success:

1. Sure, we can do it.  But, it will cost you... A lot.
2. Whip out the [Jakob Nielsen studies](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/9710a.html). Most users will neither notice nor care about trivial cosmetics.
3. Tell em (and show em), "Functionality and features first. Minor aesthetics later."  This smart approach is diabolically good because "Feature X" and "Bug Y" are ALWAYS more important to the good clients than rounded corners on MSIE 6.
4. Suppose I was selling decals.   Would you expect a decal to look the same on rough wood as on smooth glass?  On a dirty floor? Someone's cheek?   Decals are used all of these places but no one tries to make the same decal work everywhere; it's not practical.   Web browsers are even more diverse and there's thousands of permutations.
   (A dress analogy also worked.)

For the rest, I second *waiwai933* (and others):

1. Make sure functionality and general appearance are good on the top 5 browsers, but investigate gross problems that might appear on browsershots.org.
2. Code to standards and don't waste time using javascript for minor appearance tweaks...

   1. The vast majority of users won't notice or care about the difference.
   2. The offending browser will be "gone" (or used merely by bots) in months or a couple of years.
   3. If an astute user sees that the site looks slightly better in "Broswer X" than "Browser MSIE", she just might switch -- making things better for everyone.

Comment: Good answer, but browsers going in "months or a couple of years" sadly isn't always true.

Comment: IE6 is the default browser on WinXP, the most popular operating system in the world.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't need to be *exactly* the same, but you don't elements flowing outside of where it's supposed to be. If that happens, people will be sad. And then mad. And then refuse to pay you if it's on of the more popular browsers.

I highly suggest not using Javascript for visual stuff; since it's the Controller in the MVC pattern. Besides, border-radius is nice, but it's not absolutely necessary, so there's especially no reason to implement it in JS.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to check all the major browsers at least (IE, Safari, Firefox, Chrome, Opera.....) and verify that the website looks OK and functions normally.

Personally I like adding javascript to optimize for the browser you're focusing on, but be sure that it doesn't render something useless in other browsers

I've been using [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org) to get a quick look how the webite looks in multiple browsers :)

Answer (score 1):

The client pays the bills. If you don't like their rules, find a new client :)

Comment: you are very right. but how to tell client if something is really not necessary for him and his business.?

Comment: His call...  If he wants to pay for more work to get stuff perfect, cool. More $ for you.